# Retrofit not recieving JSON object

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    private String errorCode;

    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private JSONObject data;

    public KiMaResponse(String errorCode, String errorMessage, JSONObject data) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public JSONObject getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

I am doing a post call using `retrofit2` and return type of the api call is `Response`.

When Api is successful then it sends some data as json object and error as null. And when api fails then error code and error message is set and data is null.

When I am recieving response in android device in first case I am getting `data = {}` while the api fail is recieved correctly.

Note : Api call is happening properly.

```
Call<Response> cb = Services.authAPI.registerNewUser(
                        etUserName.getText().toString(),
                        hashText,
                        spRoles.getSelectedItem().toString());


                cb.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {

                        System.out.println("API RESPONSE : " + response.body().toString());

                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();

                    }
                });
```

UPDATE :
response from server

```
Response {
  errorCode: null,
  errorMessage: null,
  data:
   { userid: 1,
     role: 'FAMILY',
     username: 'shubhambhiwaniwala@gmail.com' } }
```

Response in android studio

```
API RESPONSE : Response{errorCode='null', errorMessage='null', data={}}

API RESPONSE : Response{errorCode='USER_ALREADY_EXISTS', errorMessage='user already exists', data=null}
```

Comment: can you paste the JSON reponse too

Comment: @faiizii pls check post again, i have updated it

Comment: @pz64_ there is nothing like string()

Comment: is it the same response in case of error ? because 'Reponse{ }' this body tag shouldn't be the response part

Comment: ok your api call is working well and parsing it correctly. only need to check, is your api returns data in response from server ?? do you use postman ?? if not then download it from 
https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/
and hit your api there and check response body. your api is not returning any data from server.

Comment: Yes I have tested my api using postman too. It is returning the data

Comment: ok test using providing harcode values to api methods params (android studio).if still faces the problem then may be you are not sending correct params to call apis for response
plase post few things,1)  postman snapshot(with params and response, 2) method registerNewUserName which you have written in the api interface. 
Note : the posted code have no error.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonElement instead of JSONObject. Since parser used in retrofit is Gson and Gson understands JsonElement not JSONObject

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    private String errorCode;

    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private JsonElement data;

    public KiMaResponse(String errorCode, String errorMessage, JsonElement data) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public JsonElement getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: how this will solve the problem? you should give some explanation